Rational solutions to Rational Equation
I am looking for rational solutions to
$$x\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^2}+y\frac{y^2-1}{(y^2+1)^2}=2z\frac{z^2-1}{(z^2+1)^2}$$
besides $(x, x, x)$, $(-x, 1/x, 0)$, and other similar non interesting solutions.
I am new to this type of math so I don't really have any intuition on how to approach this problem. My only thought has been to write $x,y,z$ as their fractions and look for some divisibility arguments but I didn't spot any. So I am interested in any approaches people might take, not only the solutions.
If it helps, it's equivalent to (and the reason that I am looking at this) determining if there are any three rational values of the function $f(t)=t(t^2-1)/(t^2+1)^2$ that are in an arithmetic progression.
Edit: I would like the absolute value of each term (the ones corresponding to the different variables) to have a distinct value. So for example, $(-2, 3, 1)$ gives $-24/25$, $24/25$, $0$ so I would like to avoid it.

Another obvious (and not very interesting) solution (which you probably would have found), you can set $z=y=0$ and then solve for x. You can also do this setting $x=y=0$ etc for some trivial solutions.

And what is the source of your interest in rational values of $f(t)=t(t^2-1)/(t^2+1)^2 ; ;  ? ; ; ;$

@WillJagy The values of $x,y,z$ then give the inputs for a parametrization that generates $a, b$ such that $a^2, 1, b^2$ are an arithmetic progression ($f(t)$ is one component of that parametrization). The restriction that the above equation gives is that those progressions generated from $x,y,z$ 'mesh' together: there would be two differences $n,k$ such that $(1-n, 1, 1+n), (1-k, 1, 1+k), (1-n-k, 1, 1+n+k), (1-n+k, 1, 1+n-k)$ are all progressions of squares.

There are also several integer solutions, like $(x,y,z)=(-2,3,1)$. But anyway, they are all not interesting to you, I suppose. Which solutions would like like then?

Good point. I'll add that.

You can simplify the setup by restricting to $ x, y, z \in (1 + \sqrt{2}, \infty)$.

Partial answer
Let $f(t) = \dfrac{t(t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^2}$, so that your equation can be written as $f(x) + f(y) = 2f(z)$.
It can easily be shown that the equation is satisfied if either:

$x = y = z$
$x + y = 0$ and $z \in \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$ (i.e., satisfies $f(x) = 0$).  This works because $f$ is an odd function ($\forall t: f(-t) = -f(t)$).

By brute-forcing all integers between -100 and 100, I found 40 additional $(x, y, z)$ solution sets:
$$(-3, -3, -2), (-3, -2, -3), (-3, -2, -2), (-3, 2, -1), (-3, 2, 0), (-3, 2, 1), (-2, -3, -3), (-2, -3, -2), (-2, -2, -3), (-2, 3, -1), (-2, 3, 0), (-2, 3, 1), (-1, -1, 0), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 0, -1), (-1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (0, -1, -1), (0, -1, 0), (0, -1, 1), (0, 1, -1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, -1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 0), (2, -3, -1), (2, -3, 0), (2, -3, 1), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, -2, -1), (3, -2, 0), (3, -2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 2)$$
If you want all three variables to have distinct absolute values, then possible solutions are:
$$(-3, 2, -1), (-3, 2, 0), (-3, 2, 1), (-2, 3, -1), (-2, 3, 0), (-2, 3, 1), (2, -3, -1), (2, -3, 0), (2, -3, 1), (3, -2, -1), (3, -2, 0), (3, -2, 1)$$

Sorry, I wasn't super clear, I'm looking for when $f(x), f(y), f(z)$ have distinct values, not just $x, y, z$.

@Xander: I see.  Well, none of those $(x, y, z)$ triples satisfies your requirement.  I'll see if there's a non-integer solution.
